# Converting char array to int

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;  
  void test()
    {
        int arr[10];
        int size = 0;
        int i = 0;
        char str[] = "12 45 1666";
        for(;;)
        {
            while(str[i]!='\0' && str[i]==' ')i++;
            if(str[i]=='\0')return;
            arr[size] = 0;
            while(str[i]!='\0' && str[i]!=' ')
            {
                if(!isdigit(str[i]))
                {
                    cout <<str[i]<<" - Not a number!"<<endl;
                    return;
                }
                arr[size]=arr[size]*10+(str[i]-48);
                i++;
            }
            size++;
        }
        for(int k = 0;i<size;k++)
        {
            cout <<arr[k]<<endl;
        }

    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        test();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

Here I'm trying to write a programm which convert string of figures and spaces to numeral array, but there is a problem it doesn't output. What could cause this problem. I'm a begginer to c++ so critics is welcome.

Comment: Why do you think that critics only welcome to beginners?

Comment: 1) `char str[]` -> `std::string` or `std::array<char>`. 2) I highly encourage you to learn how to use a debugger

Comment: I just began to learn c++ and don't konw how to use dynamical arrays, but thanks

Comment: please don't edit your question so that the given answers becomes incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Answer (score 1):

`return` leaves the current function. The only way out of your infinite loop is by leaving the entire function, meaning you always skip the output. Use `break` instead or supply an appropriate condition to your `for(;;)` loop.

Though c++ already provides `std::stringstream` for doing just that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream stream("12 45 1666");
    int result;

    // Reads from the stream until it's exhausted or fails
    while (stream >> result)
    {
        std::cout << result << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int k = 0;k<size;k++)
    {
        cout <<arr[k]<<endl;
    }
```

problem was here just changed 'i' on 'k'.

Comment: Good catch, but it's not the only problem.